# How To Calculate Weeks, Including Partial Weeks Since Start Of Quarter in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to calculate the week number of a quarter in MySQL.

Unfortunately, all existing solutions are based on DATEDIFF between two dates which is not what I want.

For example, today's date is Feb 24th. It is week 9 in the quarter as the first three days of January (Friday, Saturday and Sunday in this current year) were week 1.

If I do a DateDiff and simply divide by 7, it's still only giving me the number of weeks total by days. It's not giving me the calendar weeks since the start of the quarter.

```
CEIL(DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), MAKEDATE(YEAR(CURDATE()), 2) + INTERVAL QUARTER(CURDATE()) QUARTER  - INTERVAL 1 QUARTER) /7) AS WEEK_IN_QUARTER,
```

**This gives me week 8, when the expected (wanted) output is 9.**

Adding 1 to the week is going to cause problems when the opposite is true and when there's only a partial week left in the quarter or when we're 4 days into any week.

**The first week should start on the first day of the quarter and end on the Sunday of that week.**
I've been through every MySQL DATE function and I'm really stuck.

I normally do this on the client side using Python (see below) but I'd love to know if there's an easy way to do this in MySQL before trying to translate this. Any Help would be very much appreciated.

Python code if it makes what I'm trying to say a bit clearer:

```
from datetime import timedelta, date
from dateutil import relativedelta

NEXT_MONDAY = relativedelta.relativedelta(weekday=relativedelta.MO)
LAST_MONDAY = relativedelta.relativedelta(weekday=relativedelta.MO(-1))
ONE_WEEK = timedelta(weeks=1)

def get_week_in_quarter(dt):
    d: date = dt.date()
    year = d.year

    # Q0 = January 1, Q1 = April 1, Q2 = July 1, Q3 = October 1
    quarter = ((d.month - 1) // 3)
    quarter_start = date(year, (quarter * 3) + 1, 1)
    quarter_week_2_monday = quarter_start + NEXT_MONDAY

    if d < quarter_week_2_monday:
        week = 1
    else:
        cur_week_monday = d + LAST_MONDAY
        week = int((cur_week_monday - quarter_week_2_monday) / ONE_WEEK) + 2

    if quarter == 0:
        year -= 1
        quarter = 4

    return week
```

**EDIT 1:**
To further clarify, if I separate out the weeks and days on a transition day (which today is), you can see the problem:

```
SET @day1=DATE(CURDATE());
SET @day2=DATE(MAKEDATE(YEAR(CURDATE()), 2) + INTERVAL QUARTER(CURDATE()) QUARTER  - INTERVAL 1 QUARTER);
    SELECT CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(CEIL(DATEDIFF(@day1,@day2)/7),'.',1),'Weeks ',
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(ABS(DATEDIFF(@day1,@day2)),'.',1)-SUBSTRING_INDEX(ROUND(DATEDIFF(@day1,@day2))/7,'.',1)*7,'Days'
    )AS WEEKINQUARTER
```

The output is:
**8Weeks 4Days**

I don't know how to produce the required output (just "9") by dividing the days difference by 7. In Python, I have to set a delta to the last Monday to account for that. I don't know how to do that in MySQL either.

**EDIT 2**
Strawberry's answer below solved this for me in SQL. I ended up using CEIL instead of floor but for anyone looking for the current Fiscal Quarter week calculation in SQL in the future, this is a solution:

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @Strawberry I can't make this any more reproducible. There is no data set for this to work on. I've provided everything else on your link. If you care to tell me what section of your link you think I could do better, I'm happy to edit. Please don't close this without reading it.

Comment: I see. An RDBMS is for the storage and retrieval of relational data, so if there's no data, why bother doing this in MySQL?

Comment: Because I need to join two tables, one where I have the entire quarter data, another where I the data to the current week (target and attainment) and I'm calculating the attainment percentage based on the totals to show a column with the attainment totals to the current date, not to the end of the quarter. The attainment target is based on weeks, not dates. If I provided the entire query, data set and reproducible example, it would distract from what I'm trying to get answered. Which is how to calculate the current week number in MySQL when the first week can start on any day and end on Sunday

Comment: So, SELECT target WHERE targets.week < current week; I have no dates in my targets table. What edits can I make to make this question more acceptable? I'd really appreciate your input as this is the second time you've posted the same comment without offering anything specific as to what you think is missing. Can you tell me exactly what I'm missing from the link you provided that's relevant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work?

```
SELECT FLOOR(DATEDIFF('2021-02-24',CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(LAST_DAY(MAKEDATE(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM '2021-02-24'),1) + INTERVAL QUARTER('2021-02-24')*3-3 MONTH),'%Y-%m-'),'01') - INTERVAL WEEKDAY(CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(LAST_DAY(MAKEDATE(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM '2021-02-24'),1) + INTERVAL QUARTER('2021-02-24')*3-3 MONTH),'%Y-%m-'),'01')) DAY)/7) x;
```

Comment: Thanks @Strawberry (and thanks for not closing the question). This works when using CEIL instead of FLOOR, at least in all the edge cases I've tested so far as the first week is always 1. Seems the mode doesn't matter here. For context, this is ideal, as the targets table is truncated and refreshed at the start of each quarter by a third party. So it will only ever contain the current quarter numbers. It seems you were able to improve on the Python code (I completely forgot that the 7 days was a constant). Yesterday was a day I got literally nothing done because of this, so thank you!

Comment: Well test against a few more of those edge cases (because I just mashed a couple of ideas together)

Comment: Just manually went through all the first, last and middle weeks of each quarter for the next year. All are correct. Thank you so much for this. Now I can stick everything in a single view and not have to worry about scheduling additional code to run to calculate this. It actually looks great in my use case and runs fast! All stakeholders can select their own frontend (mine, sheets, Excel etc) and nothing has to be updated. Really appreciate you spending the time on doing this.

Answer (score 0):

`week()` with mode `3` is the ISO week, which is what I think you want.
You can get the week of the quarter by using arithmetic.  The first 13 weeks are in Q1, 14-26 in Q2, 27-39 in Q3 and the rest in Q4.

So:

```
select (case when week(date, 3) <= 13 then week(date, 3)
             when week(date, 3) <= 26 then week(date, 3) - 13
             when week(date, 3) <= 39 then week(date, 3) - 26
             else week(date, 3) - 39
        end)
```

There are tricks you can use to simplify this using modulo arithmetic, but I think this is clearest for explaining what to do.

Comment: Thanks Gordon. 
Unfortunately, not. ISO week is still starts on Sunday, or Monday (as the mode you used shows). It still calculates the weeks from that start. If a quarter starts on a Friday, it will always be 2 or 3 days behind (as in my case)

Comment: @DaveDavis . . . ISO weeks start on Monday.  Or at least Wikipedia agrees with me (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date).

Comment: Exactly. That's what I said. I'm looking for a solution that starts on any day. Like January, where the quarter started on a Friday.